# How to use clang AST matcher usingDirectiveDecl to find using namespace directive with specific name?

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, clang-tidy

I'm trying to prototype a `clang-tidy` matcher with `clang-query` to find `using namespace` directive with a certain name like `using namespace ns1::ns2;`.

With `clang-query` I tried these variants but none is matching anything:

```
clang-query> match usingDirectiveDecl(hasName("ns1")).bind("changeNamespaceName")
0 matches.

clang-query> match usingDirectiveDecl(hasName("ns2")).bind("changeNamespaceName")
0 matches.

clang-query> match usingDirectiveDecl(hasName("ns1::ns2")).bind("changeNamespaceName")
0 matches.
```

Is `usingDirectiveDecl` the right matcher for this task?

What is the right way to find a `using namespace` directive with a specific name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears to be impossible to do this with a `clang-query` AST matcher alone.  `usingDirectiveDecl` matches `using namespace` declarations, but further restriction based on the nominated namespace is incomplete.

While [`UsingDirectiveDecl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1UsingDirectiveDecl.html) does have a name, it is simply the placeholder string `::<using-directive>`:

```
clang-query> m usingDirectiveDecl(matchesName("^::<using-directive>$"))

Match #1:

/home/scott/wrk/learn/clang/using-namespace/un1.cc:22:3: note: "root" binds here
  using namespace ns1;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Match #2:

/home/scott/wrk/learn/clang/using-namespace/un1.cc:28:3: note: "root" binds here
  using namespace ns1::ns2;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 matches.
```

It turns out we can use `hasDescendant` to filter based on a namespace *qualifier* if one is present:

```
clang-query> m usingDirectiveDecl(hasDescendant(nestedNameSpecifier(specifiesNamespace(matchesName("ns1")))))

Match #1:

/home/scott/wrk/learn/clang/using-namespace/un1.cc:28:3: note: "root" binds here
  using namespace ns1::ns2;
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 match.
```

This is filtering using the `QualifierLoc` member of `UsingDirectiveDecl`.  But there's no way to filter on what comes after the qualifier, nor if there is no qualifier at all.  The reason appears to be simply the absence of an AST matcher that would restrict `UsingDirectiveDecl` based on its `NominatedNamespace` field.

Consequently, within a `clang-tidy` check, the best you can do is use a matcher to find all `using namespace` declarations, then (in subsequent C++ code) inspect the result of calling `getNominatedNamespace()`.